# Ignore exclude variable in equals in data class Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, transient, data-class

> Is there a way like **transient** keyword in `kotlin` that will equals all other attribute except a `boolen` var

As I have numerous attributes,I thought there must be a keyword for it.

**Product.kt**

```
@Parcelize
data class Product(
    val id: Int,
    val titleLine1: String? = null,
    val titleLine2: String? = null,
    val titleLine3: String? = null,
    val name: String? = null,
    val description: String? = null,
    val brand: String? = null,
    val brandId: Int? = null,
    val imageUrlLarge: String? = null,
    val price: Double? = null,
    val originalPrice: Double? = null,
    val splashUrl: String? = null,
    val category: String? = null,
    var onDiscount: Boolean? = null,
    val unit: String? = null,
    val conversionUnit: String? = null,
    val amount: Double? = null,
    val unitPrice: Double? = null,
    val url: String? = null,
    val breadCrumb: String? = null,
    val currency: String? = null,
    val productRank: Int? = null,
    var starRating: Double? = null,
    var reviewCount: Int? = null,
    val isFavourite: Boolean = false,
    val isRecommended: Boolean = false,
    val isSuggested: Boolean = false,
    val isPointsSuggested: Boolean = false,
    val isFavoriteOffer: Boolean = false,
    val isMissingOffer: Boolean = false,
    val isReplenished: Boolean = false,
    var splashes: List<Splash>? = null,
    var forSaleOnline: Boolean = false,
    val dynamicName: String? = null,
    val dynamicUrl: String? = null,
    val isClubMatasOnlyPrice: Boolean = false
) : Parcelable
```

I want to ignore isFavourite from equals method

Comment: Nope. All constructor parameters are used in `equals`. You either have to remove the ignored properties from the constructor, or implement your own `equals`.

Comment: You can move the property from the constructor into the body of the class.